# How to rename levels in an R data.table from another data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data.tables, `dt` is a long one with an integer column `levels` in the range 1...5, and another data.table "labels" containing labels in a simple form like this:

```
labels <- data.table(V1=1:5, V2=c("Very Low", "Low", "Median", "High", "Very High"))
#    V1       V2
# 1:  1       Very Low
# 2:  2       Low
# 3:  3       Median
# 4:  4       High
# 5:  5       Very High
```

The actual `dt` is rather large, but for reproducibility a simple one will do (though in real DT levels are not that regular):

```
dt <- data.table(levels=rep(1:5, times=10))
```

How I could replace levels column in `dt` with character labels from `labels` in one go?

I could do this in manual loop (ugly!), or I could do this by adding another column, like this:

```
dt[, tmp := labels$V2[dt$level] ]
```

and then dropping column `level` and renaming `tmp`.

Is there a good data.table way to do so?

Comment: @hfty please see update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that your datasets are generated like this:

```
 dt <- data.table(levels=rep(1:5, times=10))
 labels <- data.table(V1=1:5, V2=c("Very Low", "Low", "Median", "High", "Very High"))
```

Then you can "relabel" the levels of `dt` using the `factor` function:

```
dt[, level := as.character(factor(level, labels = labels$V2))]
```

If you don't mind level being of type `factor`, you can skip the `as.character` and just do:

```
dt[, level := factor(level, labels = labels$V2)]
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest approach is joining the *data.tables*. In order to show the effect I added an `id` column to `dt` (see below). You can join the *data.tables* as follows:

```
dt[labels, on=c("levels"="V1")][order(id)] # the [order(id)] part is not necessary, but added to show the effect better
```

which gives (first 7 rows):

```
    levels id        V2
 1:      1  1  Very Low
 2:      2  2       Low
 3:      3  3    Median
 4:      4  4      High
 5:      5  5 Very High
 6:      1  6  Very Low
 7:      2  7       Low
....
```

Or probably even better:

```
dt <- dt[labels, .(id,levels=V2), on=c("levels"="V1")][order(id)]
```

which gives (first 7 rows):

```
> dt
    id    levels
 1:  1  Very Low
 2:  2       Low
 3:  3    Median
 4:  4      High
 5:  5 Very High
 6:  6  Very Low
 7:  7       Low
....
```

---

Another option is to use the `match` function with the `labels` *data.table* as a lookup table:

```
dt[, levels := labels$V2[match(levels, labels$V1)]]
```

which gives:

```
> dt
       levels id
 1:  Very Low  1
 2:       Low  2
 3:    Median  3
 4:      High  4
 5: Very High  5
 6:  Very Low  6
 7:       Low  7
....
```

---

Used data:

```
dt <- data.table(levels=rep(1:5, times=10))[,id:=.I]
labels <- data.table(V1=1:5, V2=c("Very Low", "Low", "Median", "High", "Very High"))
```